# How to enable or disable a button using knockout.js

Tags: knockout.js

I want to disable a button using knockout.js when the user clicks the button and the server is processing some data. I'm looking at the [example](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/enable-binding.html) in the knockout tutorials but appear to be missing something.

I have the `enable:` part in the `data-bind`:

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server" >
    <h1 style="text-align: center">Select the item(s) you want.</h1>
        <br />
        <br />
        <div id="buttons" style="text-align: center">
            <button data-inline="true" data-bind="click: submit, enable: canSubmit" >Submit</button>
            <button data-inline="true" data-bind="click: cancel">Cancel</button>
        </div>
```

I have set an observable in the view model to false. However, the button is
enabled on the page when the view is initialized. So I think it is a data binding issue.

```
function ViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.selectedItems = ko.observableArray([]);
    // we should start off not being able to click the submit button
    self.canSubmit = ko.observable(false);
};
```

I want to have the button enabled until the user clicks the submit button, then disable it until the server has finished doing it's thing.

```
self.submit = function () {
        // disable submit button
        self.canSubmit = false;
        // do stuff
        self.canSubmit = true;
};
```

How do you bind the `enable` observable value to the button?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're mistakenly replacing your observable with straight js variables. `canSubmit` is an observable, so change its value by calling the function:

```
self.submit = function () {
        // disable submit button
        self.canSubmit(false);
        // do stuff
        self.canSubmit(true);
};
```

The rest is fine as-is.

Answer (score 5):

You're not updating your observable value, you're changing the reference of self.canSubmit so it points to a boolean.

change your self.submit function to:

```
self.submit = function () {
        // disable submit button
        self.canSubmit(false);
        // do stuff
        self.canSubmit(true);
};
```